# Passing Values from table to CTE

Tags: common-table-expression

I have a table of slot numbers, i.e. warehouse slot numbers.

```
0110H
0310H
0311H
0312H
0313H
0314H
```

The table is called WarehouseLocationLimits and the column name is “F1.” The 3rd and 4th digits of the of the above slot numbers represent a maximum number of bays in an aisle of the warehouse.

```
I have the following code
DECLARE @I INT
SET @I = 1;
WITH CTS(BAY) AS (


    SELECT @I
    UNION ALL
    SELECT BAY + 1 FROM CTS
    WHERE BAY < 5
)
    SELECT F1, LEFT(F1, 2) AISLE,  CAST(SUBSTRING(F1, 3, 2) AS INTEGER) BAYMAX, SUBSTRING(F1, 5, 1) LEVEL, BAY
    FROM WarehouseLocationLimits WL, CTS
    Where F1 IS NOT NULL
    order by F1, BAY
```

Which generates something like the following:

```
0110H   01  10  H   1
0110H   01  10  H   2
0110H   01  10  H   3
0110H   01  10  H   4
0110H   01  10  H   5
0310H   03  10  H   1
0310H   03  10  H   2
0310H   03  10  H   3
0310H   03  10  H   4
0310H   03  10  H   5
```

Note: for each “slot” the CTE is generating 5 lines because of the literal ‘5’ in the WHERE clause of the CTE. I need to pass the value CAST(SUBSTRING(F1, 3, 2) AS INTEGER) of each slot to the CTE. How can I do that?

Thanks in advance for your help

Clyde

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I got it. The solution is the following:

```
WITH CTS(SLOTNO, AISLE, BAY, LEVEL) 
    AS (
        SELECT F1, LEFT(F1, 2),  SUBSTRING(F1, 3, 2), ASCII(SUBSTRING(F1, 5, 1))
        FROM WarehouseLocationLimits WL1
        WHERE F1 IS NOT NULL
        UNION ALL
        SELECT WL2.F1, LEFT(WL2.F1, 2),  BAY, LEVEL - 1
        FROM WarehouseLocationLimits WL2, CTS
        WHERE WL2.F1 = CTS.SLOTNO AND LEVEL > ASCII('A')
        )
    SELECT *, CHAR(LEVEL)
    FROM CTS
    order by SLOTNO, LEVEL DESC
```

I didn't understand that the first query (i.e., that one atop the "UNION ALL" is a "seed" query and runs only once for each row of the table. Having understood that, it all fell into place for me.